# AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'mainloop'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#creating a label widget
myLabel = Label(root, text="Module selection")
#displaying it on the screen
myLabel.pack()


root.mainLoop()
```

so I'm just watching this very simple tkinter tutorial video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXPyB4XeYLA

and I'm already getting this error. I followed his steps exactly. Is this code out of date?

Comment: It's not `mainLoop()` it is just `mainloop()`

Comment: i made a silly mistake of not watching the video, he gets the same error as me but beacuse u didnt watch the video i didnt know he got the same error as me lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just used camelcase for the `mainloop()`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#creating a label widget
myLabel = Label(root, text="Module selection")
#displaying it on the screen
myLabel.pack()


root.mainloop()
```